# VueJS Datepicker change the position day and month

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, date-formatting, vuejs-datepicker

I am using this datepicker - [vuejs-datepicker](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker#readme). Current date format is MM.DD.YYYY, but I need it in DD.MM.YYYY format. For this I used the following customFormatter function.

```
customDatepickerFormatter: function (date) {
      return moment(date).format("DD.MM.YYYY");
    },
```

However, the input for example 21.09.2022 is rejected because vuejs datepicker interprets the date as 09.21.2022 which is obviously not a valid date. Can you help me fix this?

Comment: The formatting function probably doesn't like the `.` to be honest. Try with `'DD MM YYYY'` as shown here: https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker#function-formatter

Comment: Btw, if you could not use Moment, it would be better overall since this project is now done. Far better alternatives exist as written in the link above.

Comment: Unfortunately, the formatting itself is not the problem. 'DD MM YYYY' does not work either. 'MM.DD.YYYY' would work again, but is not in the desired format. Thanks for the tip with Moment @kissu.

Comment: Oh, you want to have `date` as having the order of day at first, rather than the US format. I wish to have that one too somehow but I'm not sure how to achieve that since it's probably a standard now. You could use a function before `format` to reorder your stuff from an EU towards an US format.

Comment: exactly, that's what I need. But your answer put me on the right search word. I think I found exactly what I / we need [vuejs-datepicker-europedateformat](https://vuejscomponent.com/vuejs-datepicker-europedateformat). @kissu

Comment: Not sure that a package is needed for just that but eh, if you're happy with it... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would integrate a simple but friendly formater supporting EU formatting.

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <div>
      Input your date (DD MM YYYY format)
      <input type="text" v-model.lazy="date" /> <!-- updating on focus lost -->
    </div>
    <p>result: {{ formatted }}</p>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { format } from "date-fns";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      date: "20 11 2020", 
    };
  },
  computed: {
    formatted() {
      let [day, month, year] = this.date.split(/\D/) // safe for the separation
      return format(new Date(year, month - 1, day), "PPP") // month - 1 offset is to make it simpler to compute
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This is how it looks

[image]

---

Otherwise it looks like this package could also be a nice fit for you [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73803355/vuejs-datepicker-change-the-position-day-and-month#comment130320414_73803355): https://vuejscomponent.com/vuejs-datepicker-europedateformat